# Silverlight ToolKit Chart: Hide xaxis labels

Tags: silverlight, charts

Basically I have a chart with multiple bar series. The independent value for all the series are the same. So the chart's xaxes are rendered with stacked of same independent values.

If I want to make all series (except for the first one) xaxes' labels to not visible, how can i do that in the xaml declaration?

Can anyone please give me assistance on this?

Update:

I have come across example with the following code:

```
<toolkit:Chart x:Name="myChart" Width="600" Height="400">
<toolkit:LineSeries                 
Title="Tasks"
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}"
DependentValueBinding="{Binding Task}">                       
</toolkit:LineSeries>

<toolkit:LineSeries                 
Title="Benefits"
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}"
DependentValueBinding="{Binding Benefits}">               
</toolkit:LineSeries>

<toolkit:Chart.Axes>
<toolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Location="Left" Title="First" />
<toolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y"  Location="Right" Title="Second" />
</toolkit:Chart.Axes>            
</toolkit:Chart>
```

If you plot the above code, you will see that both series will base the Y values from the left one. How can we change it so that first series will be plotted against Y values on the left and second series to be plotted against Y values on the right.

is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to share all of the XAML for your chart?  I put wrote a simple test application but I wasn't able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: example added, hope you can show some direction. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want using the `DependentRangeAxis` properties of the `LineSeries` objects.

First, give each Y-axis an `x:Name`, for example `TaskAxis` and `BenefitsAxis`.

Then, you can tell a LineSeries to use an axis by adding to it the property

```xml
DependentRangeAxis="{Binding ElementName=TaskAxis}"
```

or

```xml
DependentRangeAxis="{Binding ElementName=BenefitsAxis}"
```

as appropriate.

The full XAML of the chart then becomes

```
    <toolkit:Chart x:Name="myChart" Width="600" Height="400">
        <toolkit:LineSeries                 
                Title="Tasks"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data1}"
                IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}"
                DependentValueBinding="{Binding Task}"
                DependentRangeAxis="{Binding ElementName=TaskAxis}">
        </toolkit:LineSeries>
        <toolkit:LineSeries                 
                Title="Benefits"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data1}"
                IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}"
                DependentValueBinding="{Binding Benefits}"
                DependentRangeAxis="{Binding ElementName=BenefitsAxis}">
        </toolkit:LineSeries>
        <toolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <toolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Location="Left" Title="First" x:Name="TaskAxis" />
            <toolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Location="Right" Title="Second" x:Name="BenefitsAxis" />
        </toolkit:Chart.Axes>
    </toolkit:Chart>
```

---

Another approach is to move the `Axis` objects inside the LineSeries.  A demonstration of how to do this can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2008/12/09/silverlight-charting-gets-a-host-of-improvements-silverlight-toolkit-december-08-release-now-available.aspx).

Comment: thanks. that fixes my first problem. But I still can't change it to the final version that i wanted. Please have a look at this post if you have the time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050691/silverlight-toolkit-chart-multiple-series-with-bar-and-line