# Silverlight Toolkit chart: Multiple series with bar and line

Tags: silverlight, charts, line, bar-chart

I am having problem to show the grid in a way that I wanted. But I am also not sure whether it is possible to do that in the Silverlight toolkit chart. So any help or direction on this would be appreciated.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
<charting:Chart x:Name="myChart" Width="600" Height="400">
<charting:BarSeries                 
Title="Tasks"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data1}"
IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}"
DependentValueBinding="{Binding Task}"
DependentRangeAxis="{Binding ElementName=TaskAxis}">
</charting:BarSeries>
<charting:LineSeries                 
Title="Benefits"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data1}"
IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}"
DependentValueBinding="{Binding Benefits}"
DependentRangeAxis="{Binding ElementName=BenefitsAxis}">
</charting:LineSeries>
<charting:Chart.Axes>
<charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Location="Left" Title="First" x:Name="TaskAxis" />
<charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Location="Right" Title="Second" x:Name="BenefitsAxis" />
</charting:Chart.Axes>
 </charting:Chart>
</Grid>
```

Given the above snippet, is it possible to have the Yaxis on the left to show the month and the top x-axis to show the tasks value, and bottom x-axis to show the benefits value.

So in a way, it is sharing the Yaxis for the month. and it can use either top/bottom x-axis or even right Yaxis to plot the tasks and benefits value.

What do you guys think?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below has the task axis on the top and the benefits axis on the bottom, with a shared Y-axis on the left:

```
<toolkit:Chart x:Name="myChart" Width="600" Height="800">
    <toolkit:BarSeries                 
            Title="Tasks"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data1}"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Task}"
            DependentRangeAxis="{Binding ElementName=TaskAxis}">
    </toolkit:BarSeries>

    <toolkit:BarSeries                 
            Title="Benefits"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data1}"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Benefits}"
            DependentRangeAxis="{Binding ElementName=BenefitsAxis}">
    </toolkit:BarSeries>

    <toolkit:Chart.Axes>
        <toolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Location="Top" Title="Task" x:Name="TaskAxis" />
        <toolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Location="Bottom" Title="Benefits" x:Name="BenefitsAxis" />
    </toolkit:Chart.Axes>
</toolkit:Chart>
```